# amplify subscription using auth in swift

Tags: swift, authentication, graphql, aws-amplify

I want to set up a list of live list of "Move"s so I used this snippet from the amplify docs.

```
 func createSubscription() {
        subscription = Amplify.API.subscribe(request: .subscription(of: Move.self, type: .onCreate))
        dataSink = subscription?.subscriptionDataPublisher.sink {
            if case let .failure(apiError) = $0 {
                print("Subscription has terminated with \(apiError)")
            } else {
                print("Subscription has been closed successfully")
            }
        }
        receiveValue: { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let createdTodo):
                print("Successfully got todo from subscription: \(createdTodo)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Got failed result with \(error.errorDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Schema auth rules

```
type Move 
  @model 
  @auth( rules: [
    { allow: owner, ownerField: "owner", operations: [create, update, delete, read] },
  ]) 
{
```

But since I added auth to the "move" type I get this error. `GraphQLResponseError<Move>: GraphQL service returned a successful response containing errors: [Amplify.GraphQLError(message: "Validation error of type MissingFieldArgument: Missing field argument owner @ \'onCreateMove\'", locations: nil, path: nil, extensions: nil)]`

and `Recovery suggestion: The list of GraphQLError contains service-specific messages`

So everything is working locally but I think I need to pass the authorization to the request but I can't find any way to do it. any Ideas how I might get this request to process properly?

Answer (score 0):

got it working by writng my own request and passing the owner field directly

```
extension GraphQLRequest {
    static func newMoves() -> GraphQLRequest<Move> {
        let operationName = "getMove"
        let document = """
        subscription MySubscription {
          onCreateMove(owner: "MyUser") {
            accerationMagnitude
            id
          }
        }

        """
        return GraphQLRequest<Move>(document: document,
//                                    variables: [],
                                    responseType: Move.self,
                                    decodePath: operationName)
    }
}
```